# Bluetooth problems

Tags: bluetooth, a2dp

I have been facing an issues and can't quite figure it out. I have paired my Samsung Earbuds pro to my Ubuntu (latest version), but the quality of the voice is very very bad. I've followed many instructions, but couldn't fix it. A2DP is missing from the sound setting, it only gives me 3 other options (HSP/HFP, codec CVSD, codec mSBC).

Comment: Have you been able to fix this? I have the same issue with "True Wireless Earbuds" by Contact mobile accessories, bluetooth 5.1, EDR/BLE. Did the below answer work, or have you found another solution?

Answer (score 0):

try this sudo add-apt-repository ppa:aglasgall/pipewire-extra-bt-codecs

and then sudo apt update

restart machine
good luck

Paul

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).